# stdin.readLineSync() não aceita caracteres acentuados / especiais

Tags: flutter, dart

Sou iniciante em Dart e estou rodando um programinha no terminal do VS Code que lê uma String fornecida pelo usuário. O problema é que se uma das letras informadas for acentuada ou for cedilha etc., essa letra é ignorada. Por exemplo: *José* me retorna *Jos*, *Estêvão* me retorna *Estvo* etc.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  stdout.write('Escreva um nome: ');
  String? nome = stdin.readLineSync(encoding: utf8);
  print('Nome escolhido: $nome.');
}
```

Testei com as seguintes letras, e nenhuma delas é atribuída à variável `nome`: áéíóúàèìòùâêîôûçÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÇäüöÄÜÖß.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Estou rodando no Windows, ainda não testei no Ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

tenta usar latin1  no encoding e veja se acontece algo diferente

```
void main() {
  stdout.write('Escreva um nome: ');
  String? nome = stdin.readLineSync(encoding: latin1);
  print('Nome escolhido: $nome.');
}
```